# looping until the output of a command produces an stderr

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Normally, in bash, if I wanted to loop until a command produced a certain output I'd do this:

```
while : ; do
    status=$(mycommand)
    [ "$status" = "whatever" ] && break
    printf "."
    sleep 10
done
```

But how would I do that I wanted to loop until I got stderr output? I thought maybe I could do this:

```
while : ; do
    status=$(mycommand 2>&1)
    [ "$status" = "whatever" ] && break
    printf "."
    sleep 10
done
```

But when I do that I get this error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `2' error.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no syntax error in your the code you posted. I suggest that you look at your script with a hex editor - maybe you have some noise characters in between.

Comment: I would do `while ! mycommand 2>&1 | grep -q whatever; do`